# target id in inline SVG with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I would like to target an `<a>` tag's ID inside an inline SVG that is being used as a responsive image map. I don't need to manipulate the SVG, just launch a modal with fancybox by that ID if someone clicks on that `<a href...>`. (launch an iframe of a local page in this case)

I have read a dozen threads related to this and understand there is a namespace issue but I'm a JS noob and cant quite put it together - thank you for taking a look!
I did try the $('a[xlink\:href=#shows]’) but no joy.

---

```
<div id="inline-svg">

  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1920 1280" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" width="100%" height="100%">
    <a xlink:href="http://www.facebook.com/" xlink:title="Facebook" xlink:show="new" id="facebook">
        <rect x="1102" y="392” width="102" height="104" style="fill:#ec2024;opacity:0.5”/>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="http://twitter.com/" xlink:title="Twitter" xlink:show="new" id="twitter">
        <rect x="1102" y="520" width="102" height="104" style="fill:#ec2024;opacity:0.5”/>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="#" xlink:title="Mailing List" id=“mlist">
        <rect x="1215" y="392" width=“102” height="104" style="fill:#ec2024;opacity:0.5”/>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="shows.html" xlink:title=“Shows” id="shows" >
        <rect x="1215" y="520” width=“102” height="104" style="fill:#ec2024;opacity:0.5”/>
    </a>
    <rect width="1920" height="1280" style="fill:none"/>
  </svg>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#shows”).fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 400,
        maxHeight   : 300,
        type        : 'iframe',
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: other than the dodgy quotation marks which I assume is a copy-paste issue, accessing `$("#shows")` did return me the correct element. Don't know how this affects fancybox tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing:

```
$("#shows”).
```

to:

```
$("#shows").
```

Should work fine.

Comment: Aha! That trailing quotation mark looked correct in my code editor and the syntax highlighting was not broken - I just deleted and retyped that quotation mark and now it works. Thanks!